# "the device is not ready" when running Flutter app

Tags: flutter, gradle

I install latest version of flutter on windows 10 and when I want to run app with VScode or Android Studio, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: the device is not ready

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I already try `flutter pub cache repair` and `flutter clean` but that did not work.

Comment: I assume you have an Android device? What is the output of `adb devices`? Have you enabled USB Debugging on the device?

Answer (score 0):

run these commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```